# how i sum the total of button onclick

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<table>
    <td> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var click3 = 0;

            function onClick3() {
                click3 += 1;
                document.getElementById("click3").innerHTML = click3;
            };
        </script>

        <button type="button" onClick="onClick3()">2</button>
        <a id="click3">0</a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var click4 = 0;

            function onClick4() {
                click4 += 1;
                document.getElementById("click4").innerHTML = click4;
            };
        </script>

        <button type="button" onClick="onClick4()">2</button>
        <a id="click4">0</a>
    </td>
<table>
```

How do I calculate the sum of the number of times pressed the two buttons?

Comment: @Sumurai8 we're synchronized :)

Comment: just like you calculate the amount of clicks plus value of other counter

Comment: You want them combined?  So, if someone clicks the first button 2 times and the second button 3 times, you want to display 5 somewhere?

Comment: Yes. If someone clicks the first button n times and the second n times i want display the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
    <td> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var click3 = 0;

            function onClick3() {
                click3 += 1;
                document.getElementById("click3").innerHTML = click3;
                sumClicks(),
            };
        </script>

        <button type="button" onClick="onClick3()">2</button>
        <a id="click3">0</a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var click4 = 0;

            function onClick4() {
                click4 += 1;
                document.getElementById("click4").innerHTML = click4;
                sumClicks();
            };
        </script>

        <button type="button" onClick="onClick4()">2</button>
        <a id="click4">0</a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sumClicks() {
                document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = click3 + click4;
            };
        </script>

        <p id="sum">0</p>
    </td>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onClick="onClick3()">2</button>
<span id="click3">0</span>
<br />
<button type="button" onClick="onClick4()">2</button>
<span id="click4">0</span>
<br />
Sum:
<span id="sum">0</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var click3 = 0,
    click4 = 0;

function onClick3() {
    click3++;
    document.getElementById("click3").innerHTML = click3;
    calculateSum();
}
function onClick4() {
    click4++;
    document.getElementById("click4").innerHTML = click4;
    calculateSum();
}
function calculateSum() {
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = click3 + click4;
}
</script>
```